# EAP 7.4.8 jboss-client.jar throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jboss

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/modules/ModuleLoadException
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.getDefault(EJBClientContext.java:110)
        at org.wildfly.common.context.ContextManager.getPrivileged(ContextManager.java:286)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.getCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:861)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:116)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.sendResponse(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 9 more
```

Hello, after updating the Jboss to newer version, it started to throw above error. obviously it cannot find `jboss-client.jar` but i do not understand why?  any hint will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm posting as a comment because it requires a subscription to see this, but https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6981120.

Comment: yes i saw it, but cannot view it, plus it says `SOLUTION IN PROGRESS ` which means there is no solution for it yet

Comment: There is a solution in that document. I apologize I can't share more other than a patch is required. I assume you've got a Red Hat account given the version of JBoss EAP being used.